# Do something only in firs step of for loop in parallel

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach, parallel-processing

I would like to execute commands in first step of for loop and other list of commands in all steps of the same for loop. It is easy to do that in non-paralel loop:

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  if (i == 1) {
    print("First step")
  }
  print("Same code")
}
```

but I would like to execute for loop in parallel, that is write foreach loop, which means `i` would not be equal to 1 for all nodes (processes). Non-paralell foreach loop is:

```
library(foreach)
foreach(i = 1:5) %do% {
  if (i == 1) {
    print("First step")
  }
  print("Same code")
}
```

How to execute `print("First")` in only first step for every node?

Comment: What about just performing the first step and only then parallelize?

Comment: I don't think that would work since I have to execute this code on Azure batch in the end, so everything should be inside one foreachloop.

Comment: Hmm, not much clear to me. You can always make a loop consisting of just one step. I guess you should describe better your needs.

Comment: I need for loop of n steps, not one. But few lines of code should be executed in only first step, and other in all steps. Everything should be inside one for(each) loop and executed in parallel (which means that for some processes first i would be 2, 3 etc). More concretely, I need to set web driver using RSelenium in first step and than work with it in all other steps, but I think it is not important what is the code for first step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cl <- makeCluster(3, outfile = ""))
do_print <- TRUE
foreach(i = 1:5) %dopar% {
  if (do_print) {
    print("First step")
    do_print <- FALSE
  }
  print("Same code")
}
stopCluster(cl)
```